# Custom command deletes following character

Tags: macros

Since me and others are collaborating on a document, I added a new command which can show who wrote which part. I tried the following and other variations but the same bug keeps on happening

```
\newcommand{\authorship}[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{show-Authorship}}{\todo[color=blue!40]{Author: #1}}}
or
\newcommand{\authorship}[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{show-Authorship}}{\colorbox{blue!30}{Author: #1} \\}}
```

Compiling

```
\authorship{NAME}
Abcde 123
```

Produces the desired text `Author: NAME` (In the Text, as a todo etc) but makes the first character of the following text disappear i.e.

```
Author: NAME
bcde 123
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going on / how I can fix this?

Comment: You're missing the false text for `\ifthenelse`; add `{}` before the closing brace in the two definitions.

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full (but minimal) example, not sniplets like this. A full example enables others to copy the code you are using and testing it withput adding anything. For example  where does `\ifthenelse` or `\todo` come from? (I know where, but your code does not show it).

Comment: @egreg oh wow, thanks. How did I miss that :/

Comment: @daleif Oh ok, sorry. Will provide that next time. Since someone else already helped me fix it I won't provide an example now.